# How can I set a group policy to all access on all folders except one?

Tags: files, permissions, security, group

I am currently making a test environment where users will be going through a network administration course with different levels they must complete.  Due to the nature of the course, we want to give them **almost** root access to machine.

The one exception we want to make is to stop them from being able to access one folder in the machine.  This is the folder where we will have programs for the testing environment that checks to see if they have completed the level successfully.

Does anyone have a good way of giving someone basically root access, but restricting one folder?  I was messing around with group privileges, and I think that might be the key to what I need.

Comment: Root access is much different than allowing access to folders. One lets you run executables, the other lets you read files. Please clarify which you are after. If it's just folders/files, filesystem ACLs would do just fine.

Comment: We want to give them root access.  I say almost root access because we want the one restriction of not being able to read, write, or execute in a single directory.

Comment: They will need to do several things that only a sudo user can do such as start and stop services, install or uninstall packages, ect.